# xampp component status check failure [133278]?

Tags: xampp

this errors pops up when executing xampp control panel, anyone what it means and how to resolve it?

Comment: I am getting this error too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I moved the xampp directory to a different place and run setup_xampp.bat. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yeah, I moved my xampp folder onto a fresh PC and ran the installation over the top of it.  Got the same error as the original poster.  For some reason setup_xampp.bat didn't help until I renamed the directory and ran the .BAT file again.  I also found I had to edit my Apache httpd.conf because some of the folder paths had gotten corrupted (like C:C:/xampp/... for some reason).

Answer (score 2):

I installed from the ZIP file instead of the Windows Installer, and this resolved my issue. Appears to be a [known bug with the Installer on Win 7 64 bit](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=44448&p=173565&hilit=component+status+check+failure#p173567).

Comment: This was the only way i could install without problems under Win 7 64bits

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on two different computers (XP and Win 7 32 bit), with varying error numbers.

On my Windows XP the problem was due to [something else listening on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows).
On my Win 7, I renamed the folder to something else and ran setup_xampp.bat and it solved it.

Renaming the folder back to the original name (C:\XAMPP) and running the setup brought the problem back, so I ended up leaving it C:\XAMPP2.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to put the path to the xampp folder into the registry node.
Below is the .reg example.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\xampp]
"Install_Dir"="C:\\xampp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove Key "Install_Dir" completely from Windows Registry [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\xampp] and Xampp Control will start without error message. Xamp Control then shows "No installer package found" in status window after start.

Answer (score 0):

I have XAMPP on my USB and I think the problem is that you have to relotact it by running the setup_xampp.bat file in the root folder.

Make sure you do you not use fixed letters if it is on a removable device.

Comment: @dave maybe try reinstalling it. What version do you have?

Comment: @benny, i just installed the latest xampp version:http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: @dave have you tried the fourms as an control panel bug? I am using 1.7.3