# Component Status Check failure in xampp?

Tags: xampp

I'm getting this error message come up when I start running XAMPP:

```
XAMPP Component Status Check failure [1307908].
Current directory: (C)
Run this program only from your XAMPP root directory.
```

The thing is, once it's gone, the software then works absolutely fine!? It's all installed in the C:/XAMPP folder so that's not the problem so, has anyone got any idea why this is happening?

cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xampp component status check failure \[133278\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910300/xampp-component-status-check-failure-133278)